# Why is the phase difference an "odd number of half-wavelengths" when two waves interfere destructively?

Tags: waves, interference, wavelength, superposition

Excerpt from the Feynman Lectures, Volume III, [Quantum Behavior](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html) (emphasis mine):

> At those places where the two waves arrive at the detector with a phase difference of π (where they are "out of phase") the resulting wave motion at the detector will be the difference of the two amplitudes. The waves “interfere destructively,” and we get a low value for the wave intensity. **We expect such low values wherever the distance between hole 1 and the detector is different from the distance between hole 2 and the detector by an odd number of half-wavelengths**. The low values of $I{_1}{_2}$ in Fig. 1–2 correspond to the places where the two waves interfere destructively.

Figure 1-2, where:

- $I{_1}{_2}$ are the waves measured by the detector when both hole 1 and hole 2 let the source emit waves through them (i.e. no hole is sealed)
- $I{_1}$ is what waves gets emitted when hole 2 is sealed
- $I{_2}$ is what waves gets emitted when hole 1 is sealed

[image: Figure 1-2]

Why are the lowest values obtained when the distance between hole 1 and the detector is different from the distance between hole 2 and the detector by an *odd number of half-wavelengths*, specifically?

Comment: Because when one wave travels $\lambda/2$ more than the other then they are of opposite sign but when the difference is $\lambda$ then they are of the same sign.

Comment: Please use a graphical program and draw the following: $sin(x) + sin(x+\phi)$ for $x=0:5*2\pi$. Start at $\phi=0$ and then change the value of $\phi$. Of course you could also use trigonometric relations to solve this question, but in my experience it is best to visualise it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of question posted by the same user : [Are two waves out of phase only when the phase difference is $\pi$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598525/are-two-waves-out-of-phase-only-when-the-phase-difference-is-pi)

Comment: @sammygerbil I didn't realise that they are the same question.

Comment: I've been mulling over this today and I am still in favour of separating the two posts. The other question is about the "out of phase" terminology, whereas this one is about "destructive interference". For a trained physicist they might mean the same thing but not for people like me - I am a noob, have no training in the field and I don't know any expert personally who I can bug with my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual for waves to be graphed with the sine function (they follow a sine-like motion in real-life), so let's use it here!

Consider the following two functions:

- $y1 = sin(x)$
- $y2 = sin(x + \pi)$ (we say this is pi-shifted with respect to the first function)

If you plot y1 and y2 with a mathematical software like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculato), you see the graph below. Note that y1 is red and y2 is blue.

[image: Desmos Graph of Sine Function]

See the top-most (called crest) and bottom-most (called trough) points on the vertical axis reached by y1 and y2, respectively? These occur when the value on the horizontal axis is a multiple of "$\pi/2$".

Now, recall that:

1. The wavelength is the distance of a "cycle". Take the horizontal length between any two crests, or any two troughs, and what you get is called the wavelength. In physics, this is notated with the $\lambda$ symbol (the Greek letter Lambda). In the plot above, the wavelength has a value of $\pi$.
2. The amplitude is the height from the centre line to either the crest or the trough.
3. Destructive interference happens when the squared amplitude of the sum of the waves is lower than the sum of the squared amplitudes of the waves.

Therefore, the interference between two waves is the "most destructive" when the phase difference is an odd number of half-wavelengths, as shown in the plot above with the "$\pi/2$", "$3\pi/2$", "$5\pi/2$" points on the horizontal axis.